# Deleting an answer to one's own question will have a negative impact on your accept rate

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I has happened twice to me now that a moderator deletes the answer to my own question and converts it to a comment on the original post. This, however, negatively affects my accept rate unless I accept an other answer of which I do not really think it does answer my question. I would like this doubtless well intended moderation to stop ;-)

Comment: You should provide links to the question/comments in question, otherwise this means nothing in a vacuum.

Comment: Was your answer an actual useful answer, and not just 'I solved it myself'?

Comment: It is likely that the answer so deleted was substandard in some way. Perhaps you could provide a link to the question in question?

Comment: getting a downvote on one's very first question on Meta is not very NOOB friendly... I deleted the last question entirely as it was badly phrased to begin with.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. If it's the question I think it is, you self-answered with a comment (Not an Answer), and the moderator action is legitimate.

Comment: Down-votes are different on meta.

Comment: While it is nice you care about your accept rate, its more important that we keep our standards for what is and is not an answer high.

Answer (score 4):

Do not obsess over your accept rate.

Only accept answers that helped you the most in solving your problem.

A 90% accept rate is a better than most people on the site.

Comment: In addition, one or two deleted/accepted answers (a very rare occurrence) will have minimal, if any impact on your accept rate.